# Vscode API - provideTextDocument not executing more then once

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, ftp, vscode-extensions

I am writing a Vscode FTP extension following [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/master/tree-view-sample/src/ftpExplorer.ts#L148) example.

My problem is that it seems that `provideTextDocumentContent` only gets called once per file.. opening the file again does not recall the function. Instead it just shows you the content already loaded.

Refer to code below:

```
public provideTextDocumentContent(uri: vscode.Uri, token: vscode.CancellationToken): vscode.ProviderResult<string> {
    console.log('uri.path');
    return this.model.getContent(uri).then(content => content);
}
```

and these are my results when clicking items on my View

```
log=> '/index.cfml'   // Clicked on index.cfml
log=> '/login.cfml'   // Clicked on login.cfml
log=>                 // Clicked on index.cfml
log=>                 // Clicked on login.cfml
log=> '/signup.cfml'  // Clicked on signup.cfml
```

Expected results would be:

```
log=> '/index.cfml'   // Clicked on index.cfml
log=> '/login.cfml'   // Clicked on login.cfml
log=> '/index.cfml'   // Clicked on index.cfml
log=> '/login.cfml'   // Clicked on login.cfml
log=> '/signup.cfml'  // Clicked on signup.cfml
```

As you can see `provideTextDocumentContent` gets called the first time I click on an item but the second time I click on the same item it does not get called. Any idea why this is happening or how I could force vscode to call it for every click?

**EDIT:**
I currently have an `onDidChange` event at the top of my data provider but the implementation may be wrong. Below is a rundown of what my data provider looks like.

```
export class FtpTreeDataProvider implements vscode.TreeDataProvider<FtpNode>, vscode.TextDocumentContentProvider {

private _onDidChangeTreeData: vscode.EventEmitter<any> = new vscode.EventEmitter<any>();
readonly onDidChangeTreeData: vscode.Event<any> = this._onDidChangeTreeData.event;

constructor(private readonly model: FtpModel){ }

public refresh(): any {
    this._onDidChangeTreeData.fire();
}

public getTreeItem(element) {/*some code*/}
public getChildren(element) {/*some code*/}
public getParent(element) {/*some code*/}

public provideTextDocumentContent(uri: vscode.Uri, token: vscode.CancellationToken): vscode.ProviderResult<string> {
    console.log(uri.path);
    return this.model.getContent(uri);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Matt Bierner said:

> "If you wish to update an existing document's content, implement the
>   onDidChange event on TextDocumentContentProvider and use it to signal
>   that VS Code should call provideTextDocumentContent"

My problem was that I had to fire() `_onDidChange` with an uri.
I ended up adding this line to my `getTreeItem` method:

`this._onDidChange.fire(element.resource);`

now each item is freshly downloaded on opening.

Answer (score 4):

VS Code will reuse the provided content as long as the document is open. Switching away from a document closes its editor but does close the document itself. If you fully close the document (in all tabs), you should see the provider invoked when you open a new document.

If you wish to update an existing document's content, implement the `onDidChange` event on `TextDocumentContentProvider` and use it to signal that VS Code should call `provideTextDocumentContent`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you take a look at my edit and point me from there?

Comment: What isn't working? When is `refresh` being called?

Comment: Yes, refresh is called but the `TextDocumentContentProvider` does not get called again.

Comment: You need to implement the `onDidChange` event from `vscode.TextDocumentContentProvider `. Your current example only shows `onDidChangeTreeData` from `TreeDataProvider` being implemented

Comment: My `treeDataProvider` implements the `textDocumentContentProvider`? So my assumption was that it would be affected by the `onDidChange` seeing as they are both contained within the same class. How would I go about implementing it for the `ContentProvider`?

Comment: [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/master/virtual-document-sample/src/extension.ts) seems to be doing the same thing although not the same scenario

Comment: You example only implements the `TreeDataProvider` change event: `onDidChangeTreeData `. Just rename `onDidChangeTreeData` to `onDidChange`. They are different events

Comment: Thanks for the patience. I tried changing the event but I still have the same problem. The `provideTextDocumentContent` does not update the content. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/qny724j6/) is my class where I use the `onDidChange` event

Comment: Following [this guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/virtual-documents) all should be in order after adding the `onDidChange` event as you said. Any idea what could cause it not to refresh the virtual data content?